# Cannot prevent css inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance

I constantly fail to prevent a submenu item from inheriting the color of a top item. I know that similar questions have been asked already but am sorry to not be able to solve my problem using them.
CSS:

```
.Topmenu a{
  color:black;}
.Topmenu.update a{
  color:blue;}
.Submenu a{
  color:black;}
```

Now the Menu itself looks like this:

```
<div id='Mainmenu'><ul>
<li class='Topmenu update'><a href='Link1'>Link1</a><ul>
<li class='Submenu'><a href='Link2'>Link2</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

Now the submenu Link still is blue. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry for the confusion, it's a 2D-Menu, the Main Menu(Topmenu items) is horizontal with vertical Topmenu's (Submenu Item).

Comment: At first you never close your first `<li>` there is an `<ul>` behind your first list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). The `.Submenu` class is overwritten by `.Topmenu.update`. To avoid this, put `.Topmenu.update` in front of the `.Submenu` class.

```css
.Topmenu a {
  color: black;
}

.Topmenu.update a {
  color: blue;
}

.Topmenu.update .Submenu a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='Mainmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='Topmenu update'><a href='Link1'>Link1</a>
      <ul>
        <li class='Submenu'><a href='Link2'>Link2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know that .Topmenu.update .Submenu a has to be specified differently!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your css. it should look like this;

```
.Topmenu a {
  color: black;
}
.Topmenu, .update a {
  color: blue;
}
.Submenu a {
  color: black;
}
```

Notice the second block has a comma and space after the first class.

Although your HTML does have an error, it should still not affect the CSS from working right. and yes you have to fix your html it does not look right. so fix from @zowie's correction.

Let me know.

Comment: I just tried it, if i put </li> after link1, the following ul doesnt contain to that submenu, resulting in a breakdown of the whole menu. the <ul> must be contained in the topmenu- li to be a submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Use **>** for the first level:

```
.Topmenu a{
    color:black;
}
.Topmenu.update > a{
  color:blue;
}
.Submenu a{
  color:black;
}
```